# Why do I have to reverse the parameters when calling a WCF service?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF Service with a method that has 3 parameters: 1 input and 2 outputs. Eg.

```
Foo(input, out1, out2)
```

I add the service reference fine in my client code, however, when I go to call the service, visual studio doesn't recognise the parameters properly. I have to call the service as

```
Foo(out1, out2, input)
```

Why is this? I can see that the order is reversed in the reference file of the service reference, but if I change the order then visual studio gives me errors saying that they are not in the right order. Is this normal behaviour? Do I just need to call the service using the reversed parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...when I go to call the service, visual studio doesn't recognise the
>   parameters properly

The problem you are having is by design.

When the service exposes the WSDL metadata to consumers, there is nowhere in the service definition where the service operation signature is maintained in its original form.

Instead, the input and output parameters are declared in separate collections.

Now, it's the job of the Add Service Reference tooling to make an attempt at reconstructing the original operation signature for consumers from the metadata, but in this instance it cannot. The original operation signature has been lost at this point. So it just reconstructs the operation processing the output parameters collection first, and then the input parameters, hence your observed behaviour.

The only way to make this go away is to:

1. not use output parameters in your service operation definition. This is recommended anyway, as [output parameters are a code quality flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx) and should be avoided if possible, or
2. not expose metadata from the service. Consumers can call the service directly by using the actual service definition types using a [WCF channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of using a service reference. This is generally regarded as being a superior method for calling a service in WCF.

Or you could just do nothing. The consumer is still able to call the service operation right?